# Flash HTML markup in views = No output

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I want to display a Flash file from a view. I have a content type with a file field that I use to create a node and submit a Flash file (.swf).

Then I use a view to create a block showing the content of these content type nodes. I get the Flash files URL and use the code below to print it - but, no Flash is printed!

Why doesnt this work? It's HTML, isn't it? And Views should support it?

```
<embed id="[title]" width="190" height="285" wmode="transparent" loop="true" scale="noscale" allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" name="[title]" src="[field_ad_flash]" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

Comment: First, your tag is not closed : should be '/>' at the end. Did you check the source code of the page ? Is something incorrect output or is there nothing at all ?

Comment: Oh, thanks.

Yeah,and no code is printed if I have the code above saved in the view. If I just print a token, that is visible. Same thing if I add some random text before the <embed> code. It is visible.

Comment: OK, so it's because the embed tag is filtered at some point : not standard enough and probably considered unsecured. Here's a pretty hot thread about it : http://drupal.org/node/853880

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I resolved this issue:

1. I set up my view to only print the URL of the flash file.
2. THen I created a views template for that specific field.
3. In that template file i added the HTML above and printed the output - which is the flash files path - as src.
4. Done!

Answer (score 0):

I was using [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) for this purposes and of course you have to select url (path to file) to show in file field. Here is the code example (field-flash - an url to swf file and flash-image - it`s an image used when flash is disabled):

```
<?php if(isset($data->field_field_flash[0]['rendered']['#markup'])) {
     $flash= $data->field_field_flash[0]['rendered']['#markup']; 
}
if(isset($data->field_field_flash_image[0]['rendered']['#markup'])) {
     $flash_image= $data->field_field_flash_image[0]['rendered']['#markup']; 
}
 ?>
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="240" height="400" id="movie" align="top" data="<?php print $flash; ?>" >
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
<param name="movie" value="<?php print $flash; ?>" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
<img src="<?php print $flash_image; ?>" width="240" height="400" alt="movie" />
</object>
```